# impossible to get the whole Element from Web page in Python

Tags: python

I must extract some pieces of urls from a web page.

For example this one https://www.rtlplay.be/top-chef-p_8493

I rightclick, the inspect tool opens, I click on a thumbnail (see picture), a page opens.

Here is the link (https://www.rtlplay.be/top-chef-p_8493/emission-2-c_12999234)

I take this part of the link "emission-2-c_12999234" go back to main page,

Rightclick, elements, Ctrl+f and I paste this piece of url, I find it easily in the elements (see picture).

But when i use this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

# Path to the GeckoDriver executable
webdriver_path = r"C:\Users\sebastiens\Desktop\SMets Seb\geckodriver.exe"

# URL of the web page
url = "https://www.rtlplay.be/top-chef-p_8493"

# Configure the webdriver options
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Firefox in headless mode (without opening a browser window)

# Create a new Firefox webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path=webdriver_path), options=options)

# Navigate to the web page
driver.get(url)

# Extract and explore the elements
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")

output_file = "ok_recherche.txt"
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for element in elements:
        try:
            tag_name = element.tag_name
            text = element.text
            attributes = element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
            file.write(f"Tag: {tag_name}\n")
            file.write(f"Text: {text}\n")
            file.write(f"Attributes: {attributes}\n")
            file.write("-" * 20 + "\n")
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue

print("Results saved successfully in 'ok_recherche.txt'.")

# Quit the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

.. it seems to find the whole code i need, BUT it's impossible to find this url part "emission-2-c_12999234"

Why is that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tjal.png)

I would like the code to be really complete and able to return me the whole "parts" of links, so that I could assemble these to search all the links (for real) in the website.

Comment: Remember that Selenium acts in REAL TIME.  You are fetching the elements immediately after fetching the URL, and it's quite possible the whole DOM hasn't been built yet.  Try inserting a short delay in between.

Comment: _impossible to find this url part "emission-2-c_12999234"_ What do you mean "impossible"?  Do you mean that element is missing from the output text file?  Or do you mean you want a way to find **ONLY** that element?

Comment: I'm noting that "Emission 2" (episode 2) is not on the page when it first loads. Even if you allow it some time to load, or wait for some element to appear (as @TimRoberts correctly points out), you may still need to "click" some controls for the relevant link to load (ep. 2 is two clicks to the right)

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the bad writing, in fact when I load my main page and inspect element through the browser tool. I can find the piece of URL I'm looking for.  The code extracts well like 90% of what I'm looking for. However this link does not appear in the results, in my text file :s